handleSubmit React Native Formik
Reference Image to Code
Error Statement
Hi Im trying to create a Login page for an IOS app using React Native. Was following online guides and used Formik for validation. However, I ran into an issue when trying to implement handleSubmit.
export default function Login() {
const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = React.useState("");
console.log(email);
console.log(password);

const LoginSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string().email('Invalid email'),
  });
    
return (
    <Formik 
    initialValues={{email: '',}} 
    onSubmit={(value) => console.log(value)}
    validationSchema={LoginSchema}> 
    {({values, errors, handleChange, handleSubmit, setFieldTouched, touched}) => (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}> 
        <Text style ={styles.title}>  Login</Text>
        <View style={styles.email}>
        <TextInput
            style={styles.textInput}
            placeholder={'Email'}
            keyboardType='email-address'
            autoCapitalize='none'
            onChangeText={handleChange('email')}
            value={values.email}
            onSubmitEditing={(value) => setEmail(value.nativeEvent.text)}/>
            {errors.email && (
                <Text style={styles.errorText}>{errors.email}</Text>
            )}
            </View>
        <TextInput
            style={styles.textInput}
            placeholder={'Password'}
            secureTextEntry={false} //set this to true or false to hide password
            autoCapitalize='none'
            onSubmitEditing={(value) => setPassword(value.nativeEvent.text)}/>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginButton} onPress={() => handleSubmit}>
            <Text style={styles.loginText}>
            Login</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>       
        <View style={styles.signUp}>
            <Text>Don't have an account? </Text>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleSubmit}>
                    <Text style={styles.signUpButton}>Sign Up</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
)}
    </Formik>
)

}

Can you elaborate the problem with screenshot of the issue and error you are getting, sorry but context in this question is much less to answer.

Hi, added two images to the code, I apologise for poor formatting I am new to this forum

I dont think people will like to go to different link to get the required info. Is it possible to add screenshot in the description itself or you can copy the code and error in code block.

It's better if you'll just copy over the code on your question post.

the error is not on Formik it seems, those are just warnings from the TouchableOpacity and TouchableWithoutFeedback

i received an error at onPress with this statement:
No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 2, '(props: TouchableOpacityProps): TouchableOpacity', gave the following error.

replace onPress={() => handleSubmit} by onPress={handleSubmit} or onPress={(values) => handleSubmit(values)}

did you try to replace onPress={() => handleSubmit} by onPress={handleSubmit} or onPress={(values) => handleSubmit(values)}
